# Crossover frequency recommendation for double loop control

Tags: dc-dc-converter, control-system, pid-controller

In some techniques, such as Average current-mode (ACM) control, there are two loops: inner current loop and outer voltage loop. In the *Fundamentals of Power Electronics* by Robert W. Erickson, there is a design example of ACM controlled boost converter. The crossover frequency \$fci\$ of the inner current loop is one tenth of the switching frequency. The crossover frequency \$fcv\$ of the outer vlotage loop is one tenth of \$fci\$. But the author doesn't explain the reason to choose them.

Could anyone one offer some suggestions and reasons on the selections of the crossover frequency for the inner current loop and outer voltage loop? I will be very thankful if you make a summary for the three common topology (Buck, Boost, Buck-Boost) , like the summary given by Mr. Basso for single loop control ([Designing Compensators for the Control of Switching Power Supplies, page 10.](https://cbasso.pagesperso-orange.fr/Downloads/PPTs/Chris%20Basso%20APEC%20seminar%202021.pdf))(I also post it in here)!
[image: fc selection for single loop control]

Comment: There is a question related to my question and it hasn't been accepted. I think it's worth considering too. https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/440648/why-fast-inner-current-loop-and-slow-outer-loop-of-dc-dc-converter

Comment: Find the answer explaining how Mr. Basso get the summary for the single loop control: https://electronics.stackexchange.com/a/468445/310852